# total differentiability $\Rightarrow$ existence of all directional derivatives?

Tags: analysis, derivatives

f is totally differentiable in x $\Rightarrow$ all directional derivatives exist in x?
Does this hold? "all directions" does not just include the partials. It's probably true. How could I prove it?

Comment: If you write out the definition of total differentiability, and consider a specific direction to take the limit in, then that's really it.

Comment: Yes. Write the directional derivative with respect to a unit vector as a limit of a difference quotient. Write the total derivative as a limit of a difference quotient. Show that you can bound the magnitude of the first by the magnitude of the second.

Comment: Yes, and $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial u}f(x)=df(x)(u)$, for all $u$.